# Can I indicate type returned by method php with phpstorm?

Tags: php, comments, phpstorm

I use __call() magic php method to call non existing method with my own instructions.

I want know how can I indicate to phpstorm : this non-existing method returned an instance of a class?

exemple :

```
class Baz
{
   function __call()
   {
      return new Bar();
   }

   function test()
   {
      $this->foo()->bar();
   }
}


class Bar
{
   function bar()
   {
       //do something
   }
}
```

I want declare for all current class Baz :

```
/** @return foo() Bar */
```

I want PhpSotrm found the bar() method source and concider foo() like a Bar instance object.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the magic method annotations

```
/**
 * @method Bar foo()
 */
 class Baz
 {
   ...
```

Comment: if you have an idea to another similar problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520850/can-i-indicate-dynamic-type-returned-to-phpstorm I take^^