# Can I indicate dynamic type returned to PhpStorm?

Tags: php, comments, phpstorm

I have 3 classes like :

```
class Foo
{
    static function test()
    {
       return new static();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{}

class Baz extends Foo
{}
```

Now if call :

```
$var = Bar::test();
```

I want PhpStorm to identify `$var` as the `called_class`, here: `Bar`.

But, if I do `$var = Baz::test();` `$var` is `Baz` instance.

How can I get the dynamic called_class to indicate to PhpStorm what type is returned?

I there a syntax like

```
/** @return "called_class" */
```

to help PhpStorm and indicate the type?

Comment: I really don't get your question. You want something that would behave like `return static;`?

Comment: If you have a `static` method, you cannot return `$this`, as you don't presently have an instance at all. Can you edit your question to indicate what you do actually want to return?

Comment: `@return static` (for static and "proper" methods) or `@return $this` (for "proper" methods only) will work just fine.

Comment: I'm sry, yes I do a mistake with exemple. I edit : it return not "this" because it's impossible, `return new static();`

Answer (score 0):

First you have an error in your static function. You can not use

```
 return $this;
```

as the static call will not create any instance. So you have to create a new instance.

```
class Foo
{
    public static function test()
    {
        return new static();
    }
}
```

The static keyword will instantiate a new instance of the class itself.

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function fooBar(){}
}

class Baz extends Foo
{
    public function fooBaz(){}
}
```

i just added the foo functions to show you that phpStorm now will correctly find the source.

```
$var = Bar::test();
$var->fooBar();
```

$var is now an instance of Bar

```
$var2 = Baz::test();   
$var2->fooBaz();
```

$var2 is now an instance of Baz

Comment: yes I edit my mistake, I would said `return new static()` of course... But, my goal is to keep clean childreen classes. **I don't nwant to declare method in children classes.**

Comment: you don't need to. Wanted only to show that it would work and phpStorm will correctly show available functions

Comment: in fact LasyOne tell me the good answer : `/** @return static */` works!